# i get error when select max id from table when my table is no data

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have select max code from my table it work when it have data but when table is empty i got error as bellow:

Here is may code  in Repository:

```
@Repository("depositRepository")
public interface DepositRepository  extends JpaRepository<Deposit,Integer>,
   JpaSpecificationExecutor<Deposit> {  
    @Query("select max(u.code) from Deposit u")
    String getMaxCode();


}
```

And here is code i call in  service for get result:

```
String maxCode=depositRepo.getMaxCode();
```

I got error as i have mentioned below:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        max(deposit0_.code) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        rems.tbldeposit deposit0_
20:10:55,182  ERROR [rems.controller.DepositController] java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: please put the whole stack trace of the exception. Seems there is issue with your code.

Comment: I not  got any exception else from console. except as i show so i don't know what to do too. (-_-)

Comment: you need to handly a null value for u.code.  on oracle you might do this:  select max(nvl(u.code, 0)) from Deposit u

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DBMS returns null when selecting a max() from an empty record set.

It's hard to tell without seeing more code context from your service method, but I'm guessing you're later calling some operation on the getMaxCode() result, like maxCode.equals(...) or maxCode.toString(), which gives you a NullPointerException.

To avoid the exception, you can either do a null check in your java code:

```
String maxCode=depositRepo.getMaxCode();
maxCode = (maxCode==null) ? "0" : maxCode;
```

or you can tweak the query to return a default value in the event max(u.code) is null, like this:

```
@Query("select coalesce(max(u.code), '0') from Deposit u")
```